# How to get data grouped Horizontally in a crystal report

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I have two fields in my crystal report in ASP.net which gets the data from the database. So the view looks like as follows:

```
[pid]         [batch]

2108          1234
2108          5647
2108          7856
2108          3425
2109          1254
2109          1255
```

but I want the data should be grouped and to be shown horizontally like this:

```
[pid]         [batch]

2108          1234, 5647, 7856, 3425
2109          1254, 1255
```

Will you please help me out to get the solution.
I tried using the "group by" keyword in my query, but no solution.
Please Help me out.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT pid,

(STUFF((SELECT ',' + CONVERT(varchar(10), batch) FROM tblTest E2 WHERE  E1.pid = E2.pid ORDER BY pid

FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT).value('root[1]','nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'')) as batch

FROM tblTest E1 ORDER BY pid
```

above sql query will return the result set as expected.try to get the result set from sql query other than from crystal reports.